# what fontstyles are allowed for docusign RecipientSignatureInformation

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to set a signature by using RecipientSignatureInformation, but what ever fontstyle I use I get and error such as "Invalid 'fontStyle' specified for recipientSignatureInfo: 'Arial'"

What fonts are Valid?

In the API documetation for RecipientSIgnatureInformation no valid font styles are gives.

Comment: can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: Hi Jay. I've opened up a bug issue to internally investigate this (DEVDOCS-2353). I, too, don't see a listing of available options for that property. Hold tight.

Comment: try "Rage Italic", "Mistral", "7_DocuSign", see if any of these work

Answer (score 0):

We are doing to improve the documentation for this topic.

In the interim, please try these options:

```
 "Rage Italic", "Mistral", "7_DocuSign"
```